# How to use modules in dagger-2

Tags: dagger-2

I can't seem to grasp the modules of dagger.

1. Should I create a new instance of a module each time I want to inject stuff?
2. Should I create only one instance of a module? If so where should I do it?
3. Is there a more complex example of fragments and activities used with dagger?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should think more about `@Component` than `@Module`. Modules just  create objects that need further initialization. The actual work happens in Components, which modules are part of.

> Should I create a new instance of a module each time I want to inject stuff?

You should create your module when you create the Component it is part of, since only this component is going to need it. If you find yourself creating the *same* module multiple times, you are most likely doing something wrong.

A module uses additional arguments (pass them in via the constructor) to create more complex objects. So if you were to have e.g. a `UserModule` you'd pass in the a user to create user dependent objects from the resulting component. If the user changes lose the old component and create a new module and a new component—the old objects should not be used anymore.

Keep the component where / when appropriate and be sure to use *Scopes*, since they determine the lifetime of your component.

> Should I create only one instance of a module? If so where should I do it?

You most likely will just create a single instance of `@Singleton` annotated Components and Modules. In android you'd most likely keep the reference to the component (not the module!) in the `Application` or some real 'singleton'.

> Is there a more complex example of fragments and activities used with dagger?

Try googling. There are lots of high quality tutorials with linked github repositories that go into much more depth and detail as would be possible here on SO. e.g. see [Tasting dagger 2 on android](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/).